# Jquery .Show() .Hide() not working as expected

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to use the show and hide to display a different set of select options when a certain report type is selected.  I have a couple problems with this:

The .show .hide only execute properly if I pass params, slow fast, in the first result of my conditional statement.  If I take out the params or pass params in both results, only one select shows and it never changes. Here is the code that currently kind of works.

```
        if ($('#ReportType').val() == 'PbuseExport')
        {
            $('#PbuseServices').show('fast');
            $('#ReportServiceDropdown').hide('fast');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#PbuseServices').hide();
            $('#ReportServiceDropdown').show();
        }
```

After I've used this control, I am taken to a different page.  When I use the control again, it retains the original search values and repopulates the control.  Then again I only want to show one select option if a certain report is chosen. This works correctly if the report type I originally searched on is not the "PbuseExport". If I searched on the report type "PbuseExport", then both selects show on the screen, and only until I change the report type does it show only one select.  I know this probably isn't very clear.

Here is the code that handles the change event on the report type drop-down.

```
    var serviceValue = $("#ReportType").val();
    switch (serviceValue)
    {
        case 'PbuseExport':
            $('#PbuseServices').show('fast');
            $('#ReportServiceDropdown').hide('fast');
        default:
            $('#PbuseServices').hide();
            $('#ReportServiceDropdown').show();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Have you used firebug to step through the code to see if what expect is happening and it is really a JQuery problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second piece of code you also need a break after the case statement. The select will fall right through to default. Confirming....

Yep you need a break also think about just using an if statement instead of a case.

Comment: Watchout for browser caching.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my project file is corrupted..along with quite a few other major issues.. and now I have to reinstall VS
 :|

Comment: Yep, I was just about to suggest that.